# UIBarButtonItem appearance set titleTextAttributes for different styles

Tags: ios, uikit, uiappearance

Is there any way I can set different `textAttributes` (e.g. different fonts) for `UIBarButtonItem` depending on the item's `style` property when using UIAppearance?

Background: I want to globally customise the font of my apps barButtonItem via `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes`.
But when doing so the attributes (i.e. the font) will always override the item's font independent of the `style` property of the barButtonItem.

I would like to globally set different fonts for `.plain` and `.done` items.